# Generating a presigned S3 URL using PAWS

Tags: perl, amazon-s3

I have uploaded a CSV file to S3 Web Services using PAWS (that's the only Amazon Perl SDK I can use. I won't be able to use `Amazon::S3` or so on).

I am trying to get a pre-signed URL for the file I have uploaded to the S3 bucket.

Comment: You should probably submit this as an issue at https://github.com/pplu/aws-sdk-perl.